# LSQUnivariateSpline.get_coeffs() - what coefficients do I get?

Tags: python, numpy, spline

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import LSQUnivariateSpline 

x = np.linspace(-3,3,7)
y = np.sin(x)
t = [-1,1]

LSQ_USpline = LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, t, k = 3)
print(LSQ_USpline.get_coeffs())
```

As far I understand I am getting 3 polynomials pieced back together. The output of `LSQ_USpline.get_coeffs()` is

```
[-0.14112001 -0.90624802 -1.47578155  1.47578155  0.90624802  0.14112001]
```

I thought that first two coefficients are related to the first polynomial, in particular `a_0 -> -0.14112001` and `a_1 -> -0.90624802`, where a_0 is the coefficient of x^3. After plotting it I realized that it is not true.
Could somebody help me to understand what how to read output of `LSQ_USpline.get_coeffs()`?

**Update:** Overall what do coefficients of spline mean? I thought they are coefficients of polynomials of the spline.

**Update:** After differentiating and checking values at zero `get_coeffs()` is definitely not coefficients of polynomials or there is a bug in this function.

Comment: They are coefficients in the [(B-)spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline)

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish somebody could update the documentation for this function.